# How to restore PHP to the original configuration?

Tags: macos, php

I did something wrong and now my PHP is not working anymore.

I'm using OS X Lion. I can I restore it to the original configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a `/etc/php.ini.default` file that you can copy to `php.ini`.

Comment: I didn't have the `/etc/php.ini`. I did what you said but id doesn't work. If I try to open a php page in my Sites folder it shows me the code. Maybe it's a problem with apache?

Comment: Look in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and make sure LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so is uncommented.

Comment: I did it and it worked...however it was in `/private/etc/apache2`. Why do I have 2 versions? Is it normal the fact that if I go to `/localhost/~luca/phpmyadmin` it works but `/localhost/~luca/phpmyadmin/index.php` shows me the php code?

Comment: 1) /etc is just a symlink to /private/etc. And 2) no it's not normal. Maybe browser cache?